# Ran multiple instances of my program in the background at the same time, what do these return signs mean?

Tags: bash, job-control

I just kicked off a bunch of instances (17) of my program to test them running concurrently. This is what the terminal output looked like near the end.

```
    [9]   Done                    perl test.pl -a
    [10]   Done                    perl test.pl -a
    [11]   Done                    perl test.pl -a
    [12]   Done                    perl test.pl -a
    [13]   Done                    perl test.pl -a
    [14]   Done                    perl test.pl -a
    [15]   Done                    perl test.pl -a
    [16]-  Done                    perl test.pl -a
    [17]+  Done                    perl test.pl -a
```

The 17th was the last one. I was wondering, what does the [16]- and [17]+ mean? Just that they were the last two processes to finish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [§7.1 "Job Control Basics" in the *Bash Reference Manual*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Job-Control-Basics):

> Job number `n` may be referred to as ‘`%n`’. The symbols ‘`%%`’ and  ‘`%+`’ refer to **the shell’s notion of the current job, which is the last job stopped while it was in the foreground or started in the background**. A single ‘`%`’ (with no accompanying job specification) also refers to the current job. The previous job may be referenced using ‘`%-`’. If there is only a single job, ‘`%+`’ and ‘`%-`’ can both be used to refer to that job. **In output pertaining to jobs (e.g., the output of the `jobs` command), the current job is always flagged with a ‘`+`’, and the previous job with a ‘`-`’.**

(emphases mine).

So it's not that they were the last ones to finish, but that they were the last ones to be started in the background.

Comment: I picked this answer because it had the link to the man page. The other answers were helpful too. Thanks for the quick responses!

Answer (score 4):

This is from the bash man page:

> In output pertaining to jobs (e.g., the output of the jobs command),
>   the current job is always flagged with a +, and the previous job with
>   a -.

So basically **`+`** behind the **`[17]`** is because it was the last job started and the **`-`** behind **`[16]`** is because that was the previous job.

Answer (score 1):

From the `bash` manpage:

> JOB CONTROL 
>   ...
>
> ```
> When bash starts  a  job
>    asynchronously (in the background), it prints a line that looks like:
>
>           [1] 25647
> ```
>
> ...
>
> The previous job may be referenced using %-.  In output pertaining to jobs (e.g., the output of  the
>          jobs  command), the current job is always flagged with a +, and the previous job with a -.  A single % (with no accompanying job
>   specification) also refers to the
>          current job.